# Youtube get video file link

Tags: file, video, hyperlink, download, youtube

Im trying to extract the location for a saved youtube video file (like youtube downloader do).

When I use chromes developer tools I can easily see in the network section a GET request to the file. For example:

```
Request URL:ttps://r7---sn-35cxacf-43ce.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?sver=3&expire=1454883491&upn=tsTA82e-o9E&itag=251&id=o-APaDOeTiHGebIWBx11PdJn2W306GFYIoYkYRzOOCnq8o&mn=sn-35cxacf-43ce&mm=31&keepalive=yes&pl=32&ip=2a02%3A8071%3A2782%3A8c00%3Ad8e%3Aeb17%3Ab477%3Ad45b&ms=au&mv=m&mt=1454861758&ipbits=0&initcwndbps=1905000&clen=5116592&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Ckeepalive%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&key=yt6&gir=yes&fexp=3300130%2C3300161%2C3310848%2C3312381%2C3312708%2C9406984%2C9416126%2C9420452%2C9422596%2C9423661%2C9423662&mime=audio%2Fwebm&requiressl=yes&lmt=1449558944068050&dur=308.401&source=youtube&cpn=TrlaqPAJmEUJLKte&alr=yes&ratebypass=yes&signature=704658DBE8F05AC56D741F2061B2F16B0B5F37DD.6929579BD72F61B1401C96078192EC20BA8CE6EC&c=WEB&cver=html5&range=781669-1125882&rn=9&rbuf=43086
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:[*****address*****]:443
```

If I delete a few of the last params (starting at c=WEB) I got the location [(see here)](https://r7---sn-35cxacf-43ce.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?sver=3&expire=1454883491&upn=tsTA82e-o9E&itag=251&id=o-APaDOeTiHGebIWBx11PdJn2W306GFYIoYkYRzOOCnq8o&mn=sn-35cxacf-43ce&mm=31&keepalive=yes&pl=32&ip=2a02%3A8071%3A2782%3A8c00%3Ad8e%3Aeb17%3Ab477%3Ad45b&ms=au&mv=m&mt=1454861758&ipbits=0&initcwndbps=1905000&clen=5116592&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Ckeepalive%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&key=yt6&gir=yes&fexp=3300130%2C3300161%2C3310848%2C3312381%2C3312708%2C9406984%2C9416126%2C9420452%2C9422596%2C9423661%2C9423662&mime=audio%2Fwebm&requiressl=yes&lmt=1449558944068050&dur=308.401&source=youtube&cpn=TrlaqPAJmEUJLKte&alr=yes&ratebypass=yes&signature=704658DBE8F05AC56D741F2061B2F16B0B5F37DD.6929579BD72F61B1401C96078192EC20BA8CE6EC)*. But how can I get this "request URL" by code? Do I need to analyze the network traffic? Or is there an other way?

*Its getting only the sound of the video file - but thats ok. The sound starts after 4 seconds.

A second way I tried:
Getting the html-cocde of the normal youtubevideo (on youtube.com) and extracting and decoding the .googlevideo urls. But this way is not very safe, because I have to set up the url with some parameters and values which can be required or not for every video. So this way works only for every second video...

Does somebody know an other way to get the filelocation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URLs are available through the `ytplayer.config.args` object. Keep in mind if they have "secured" the video you will have to jump through some serious hoops to get a usable URL, and maybe not even then.

[How do all of these “Save video from YouTube” services work?](https://superuser.com/a/773998)

Comment: Thanks it worked:
1) Downloading source code
2) Finding the base.js url which contains the script
3) Downloading the script
4) Finding the function name
5) Grabbing googlevideo links from source code
6) Calling the script with the link signatur as parameter
7) Replacing the link signature with "signature=" + signature from script
8) Removing some queryparams in the link (in a loop and checking if the link works).
Done.